# How to Disable click event out side the button ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton

I am creating one custom button class inherit from the UIControl.
I am creating Button with Kite Shape as shown in image using Bizer Path.

## Code

## .h

## import

```
@interface CustomButton : UIControl
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;
@end
```

## .m

```
#import "CustomButton.h"

@implementation CustomButton
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
   self =  [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self)
    {
        UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath new];
        //  [path moveToPoint:(CGPoint){0, 0}];
        [path moveToPoint:(CGPoint){100,50}];
        [path addLineToPoint:(CGPoint){100, 100}];
        [path addLineToPoint:(CGPoint){150, 100}];
        [path addLineToPoint:(CGPoint){200, 0}];
        [path addLineToPoint:(CGPoint){100, 50}];

        // Create a CAShapeLayer with this triangular path
        // Same size as the original imageView
        CAShapeLayer *mask = [CAShapeLayer new];
        mask.frame = self.bounds;
        mask.path = path.CGPath;

        // Mask the imageView's layer with this shape
        self.layer.mask = mask;


    }

    return self;
}
@end
```

## VC .m

```
CustomButton *button = [[CustomButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 200)];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside] ;
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{

        NSLog(@"pressing");
}
```

## Image

[image]

## My Question Is,

When I clicked outside the button(Red Portion) It gives me a click event.
I do not want to do this.
Please help me,How can i solve it?

Thank You

Comment: its give you beacuse of your button shape is square. got it.

Comment: Ya ,That i got it,but i want only this type of button shape.How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

I am updating my answer for `UIBUtton`

**CustomButton.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomButton : UIControl
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;    
@end
```

**CustomButton.m**

```
#import "CustomButton.h"

@implementation CustomButton



-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self =  [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self)
    {
        UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath new];
        [path moveToPoint:(CGPoint){100,50}];
        [path addLineToPoint:(CGPoint){100, 100}];
        [path addLineToPoint:(CGPoint){150, 100}];
        [path addLineToPoint:(CGPoint){200, 0}];
        [path addLineToPoint:(CGPoint){100, 50}];
        CAShapeLayer *mask = [CAShapeLayer new];
        mask.frame = self.bounds;
        mask.path = path.CGPath;

        // Mask the imageView's layer with this shape
        self.layer.mask = mask;

    }


    return self;
}
```

In your controller `viewDidLoad`

```
CustomButton *buttonCustom = [[CustomButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 200)];
[buttonCustom setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[buttonCustom addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonCustom:forEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[buttonCustom setTag:1000];
[self.view addSubview:buttonCustom];
```

Add these methods in your Controller

```
-(void)buttonCustom:(UIButton *)sender  forEvent:(UIEvent*)event{
    UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:sender] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    UIColor *color = [self colorOfPoint:location];
    if([color isEqual:[UIColor redColor]]){
        NSLog(@"red ");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"White Color");
    }
}

- (UIColor *) colorOfPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    unsigned char pixel[4] = {0};

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixel, 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, kCGBitmapAlphaInfoMask & kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -point.x, -point.y);

    [self.view.layer renderInContext:context];

    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:pixel[0]/255.0 green:pixel[1]/255.0 blue:pixel[2]/255.0 alpha:pixel[3]/255.0];

    return color;
}
```

If you have multiple `UIButton` then use the `tag` property to distinguish your button.

Comment: Hey ,Sunny Make sure that my red portion is Button,So when i implement this is it good for button.I mean does the button work like on click event?

Comment: brother suppose you have more then 2 button in single view controller then how can you manage this thing ?

Comment: and ya i did not use color like [UIColor redColor] then ?

Comment: One More thing Is Button Counting in my hand,mens for example :-when I give 3 with height and width it should be give me THREE BUTTON with 120 Degree each.(Like mitsubishi Symbol).So may be it is not possible that i understood.

Comment: Updated for UIButton. check it.

Comment: Working only Red ,green and blue not any other color.